# Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova Build Error

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, cordova, npm

I have a problem while I'm trying to run my cordova project on an android device and android emulators.

I'm using visual studio 2015

i need a help please!!!

the error in the following image:

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/845229Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache

As suggested by the error message.